# Spectral sequence of filtered complex.

Tags: homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

I am trying to understand the construction of a spectral sequence of a filtered complex. After reading through the entry in the nLab I came up with an example, that I don't understand:
Consider the double complex $C_{p,q}$

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    \mathbb{Z} @<5<< \mathbb{Z} @<<<0@<<<0\\ 
@V  V V @VV 3 V@V  V V @VV V\\   
0 @<<< \mathbb{Z} @<3<<\mathbb{Z}@<<<0\\
@V  V V @VV  V@V 4 V V @VV  V\\
    0 @<<< 0 @<<<\mathbb{Z}@<4<<\mathbb{Z}\\
\end{CD}
(with $C_{0,0}$ being in the lower left corner).
Then the total complex $Tot(C)$ is as usually given by summing the antidiagonals and it is filtered by the value of $p$. 
Following the construction from the nLab (using r-almost zycles and boundaries) I get, that the $E^1$ page has the form

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    \mathbb{Z} @<<< 0 @<<<0@<<<0\\ 
@. @. @. @. \\   
0 @<<< \mathbb{Z} @<<<0@<<<0\\
@. @. @. @. \\
    0 @<<< 0 @<<<\mathbb{Z}/4@<<<\mathbb{Z}\\
\end{CD}

And the $E^2$-page has the form

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    \mathbb{Z}/5 @. 0 @.0@.0\\ 
@. @.@. @.\\   
0 @. \mathbb{Z}/3 @.0@.0\\
@. @. @. @. \\
    0 @. 0 @. \mathbb{Z}/4@.0\\
\end{CD}

And althought the $E^2$ page clearly is the homology of the double complex it is not the homology of the $E^1$ page.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't understand how you get your $E^1$ page (I believe it should be a $\mathbb{Z/3Z}$ in the second line). But more importantly, I don't understand how you get your $E^2$ page. The kernel of $\mathbb{Z\to Z/4Z}$ is not zero and should be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ (in fact it is $\mathbb{Z}$ since the differential is zero). There is no non zero differential on the $E^2$ page, however a last differential should appear on the $E^3$ page.